# Will Delayed::Job serialize ActiveRecord objects with current schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

Recently I deployed a database migration to add a timestamp called `authorized_at` to one of our models, and I realized that some of our `Delayed::Job`s threw an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `authorized_at' for #<ModelName:0x...>
```

Does delayed job lock version of the schema at the time the job is created?